# How to design a user registration page by verifying mobile number?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, verification

I want to design a user registration page in asp.net, When user enter his mobile number he will get a verification code to the entered mobile, After entering that code in the verification code textbox in registration page, if it is matched then he will be as a registered user or else the he cannot move to the process.

How can I do this, I have googled about this issue I had not understand much about it. how can I do this in the INDIAN mobile networks?

Comment: Google the "India SMS Gateway" and contact one of providers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you need some kind of SMS API to send the text, such as [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/sms/api). After this, you can generate some random number that will be sent to the user in the message, this same number you will store somewhere, maybe a database, along with the username or email address. When the user comes back with the number, you get the record by username or by the number, and compare it against the username or the number, and there you have it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7346/Sending-SMS-using-NET-through-a-Web-service). It includes options for both Worldwide and India only services.

Or else, explore some SMS gateway services and choose whatever suits you. Basic idea would be similar to what is presented in the article.